# Alternative to LibreCMC/OpenWRT that is easier to upgrade?

Tags: software-rec, openwrt, router

I use LibreCMC (based on OpenWRT) for my wifi router, and I really hate it. Every time I upgrade, everything breaks, and I have to manually log in and fix everything, by hand, and remember what I did last time. It just erases my old config files and forgets the optional packages I installed or replaced last time. There's no automation of upgrades whatsoever. Really user-unfriendly.

Is there some alternative operating system that I can run on a router that provides comparable performance but makes upgrading less of a hair-pulling experience?

I want something that will work 90%-100% if I upgrade it, maybe with some optional extras like web proxy not working that I can fix at my leisure - not with a completely failed wifi subsystem that requires logging in over an ethernet cable to fix.

Comment: I looked into using my Raspberry Pi 4 as a router, but I heard that this does not have sufficient bandwidth at the hardware level to act as a wifi router.

Comment: Odd, if it's based on OpenWRT, then upgrades should result in exactly the same configuration 99% of the time. I have OpenWRT routers that have upgraded dozens of times - the only breakage being when OpenWRT flipped some devices to using DSA - but even then it was quite painless